# PyCharm Terminal: Make Option + Arrow Keys go backwards/forwards a word

Tags: python, pycharm

Most terminal emulators allow you to configure it to make <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right Arrow</kbd> jump forward or backward a word.  Is it possible to do this in the PyCharm Terminal?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't looked at the Keymap reference from the Help menu, please do so first. I tried doing Option+Left/Right and I was able to navigate words in PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.3. Also within the IDE, type Shift+CMD+A to find any action. However, in the PyCharm Terminal (View -> Tool Windows --> Terminal, Shift+Left/Right key combination should work to navigate words.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Are you talking about the PyCharm Terminal, though? I'm asking specifically about the embedded terminal (View > Tool Windows > Terminal), and I think you might be talking about the keymap of the PyCharm Editor.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had the question confused with the PyCharm Terminal. Try using Shift+Left/Right keys. I was able to navigate word to word.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the tip, but for me that just types A/B/C/D depending on which arrow key I press. I appreciate the help anyway!